# How to speed up the sping boot UT

Tags: spring-boot, testing

Our CI pipeline is getting very slow when there are more tests.  One of the reasons is we have tests annotated as `@SpringBootTest`.  It then starts the spring application.  Trying to understand, if we don't want to change the test, if there's a way speeding up the tests other than making them parallel.